# Prometheus cannot find Apiserver of self-hosted Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I set up a Kubernetes cluster. Apiserver is started on host 192.168.0.2, and I use self-signed certificate and static token as authentication. The other 2 nodes' ip are 192.168.0.3 and 192.168.0.4

Then I created a prometheus deployment, the config is [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prometheus/prometheus/master/documentation/examples/prometheus-kubernetes.yml). In prometheus dashboard, the two nodes and prometheus self are showed as "UP". However the apiserver is showed "DOWN", and the reason is "context deadline exceeded".

```
kubernetes-apiservers
Endpoint    State   Labels  Last Scrape Error
https://192.168.0.2:443/metrics
DOWN    instance="192.168.0.2:443"  55.979s ago context deadline exceeded
```

I tried to curl the address (https://192.168.0.2:443/metrics) from node server with ca certificate and token. The result is ok.

By the way, I setup the apiserver by `hyperkube apiserver` command line instead of `kubelet`. Is this the problem? And where should I look into?

In prometheus log, I only found this related one.

```
time="2017-01-13T10:51:28Z" level=debug msg="endpoints update" kubernetes_sd=endpoint source="endpoints.go:77" tg="&config.TargetGroup{Targets:[]model.LabelSet{model.LabelSet{\"__meta_kubernetes_endpoint_port_protocol\":\"TCP\", \"__meta_kubernetes_endpoint_ready\":\"true\", \"__address__\":\"192.168.0.2:443\", \"__meta_kubernetes_endpoint_port_name\":\"https\"}}, Labels:model.LabelSet{\"__meta_kubernetes_service_label_provider\":\"kubernetes\", \"__meta_kubernetes_namespace\":\"default\", \"__meta_kubernetes_endpoints_name\":\"kubernetes\", \"__meta_kubernetes_service_name\":\"kubernetes\", \"__meta_kubernetes_service_label_component\":\"apiserver\"}, Source:\"endpoints/default/kubernetes\"}"
```

Update:

The reason is that I didn't set up calico on master node. It works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like a network issue as the request is timing out. Can you hit that endpoint from inside the Prometheus container?

Comment: I would like to try this, but the Prometheus image does not have any web tools such as curl or wget. How should I test inside the container?

Comment: It seems a good direction. I saw some log from another pod, which showing something wrong with the connection with apiserver at 443 port.

Comment: I didn't start calico-node on master server. Maybe that is the reason.

Comment: `curl` is available within `busybox`, here is a good guide https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/debugging-services/

Comment: You can always just install stuff in the container.. Depending on the base image of your container you often have access to `yum` or `apt-get`..

Comment: Thank you. It is because I didn't set up calico on master node. It works now.